# HTML5 Drag and Drop with insertBefore

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I am working on a drag and drop project.

**How**: I am using the HTML5 drag events.
**Code**: See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uWBGu/)
**Problem**: It only works sometimes, and I checked the code a million times

```
Idea:
- Get element and drag it over a div with id: LayerN (N=number)
- Create a new layer before LayerN when dropping
- AppendChild to new Layer.
- Remove empty layers if there are any.
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong or too complex?  I don't want to use a JQuery framework, i want to understand what I am doing. Thanks a lot for reading, any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't get your fiddle to work so I'm giving general comments rather than a full 'answer' so hope it helps!

For D&D I find what works best is attach a mousedown event to the document on page load (or the containing element of the draggable objects if that's more appropriate).
Don't attach any events to the draggable elements themselves at this stage.

On mousedown, check the classname/id of the target and if it's draggable:

- If you want to show it dragging, clone the element and append to a position:fixed or :absolute DIV - you can move this on mousemove relative to the cursor. Keeping this element offset to the cursor means you can still detect what's under the cursor.
- Hide the element you're dragging. You can put some sort of image showing where it came from at this stage if you wish using insertBefore.

I hide the element rather than move it because if you cancel the drag it's very easy to restore it.

Attach mousemove and mouseup events to the window or document. The function you call on mousemove can, based upon the event.target/event.srcElement, decide whether the dragged object can be dropped or not (again, I generally look for a className here).

This way you've only got a maximum of two event listeners running everything rather than multiple events on every single element.  I suspect your event listeners may be tripping over each other.

I don't know if that gets you any further, but good luck!

Comment: Thanks. Wonderful answer. Have a nice to-day!